# Change icon of alias on desktop?

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsworkspace

I have an alias of an actual application on my desktop.

Now i have to change its icon at runtime. 
I'm using,

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] 
setIcon:imgAppIcon forFile: shortCutDestPath options:0];
```

But this changing icon of original file in/Application folder. Instead of alias changing.

Comment: I don't know that you can change the icon of an alias without it changing the original, can you do it in the finder cmd i the click the image, paste in something else...

Comment: i can change that in Lion and Mountain Lion but not in Mavericks!!!

Comment: Desktop aliases are very windows things. Don't go creating those in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer, instead of creating alias create a hard link at shortCutDestPath of your application:

```
 [[NSFileManager defaultManager] linkItemAtPath:<application path>
                                                toPath:shortCutDestPath
                                                 error:&error];
```

To update icon

```
BOOL result = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] setIcon:imageIcon
                                       forFile: shortCutDestPath
                                       options:NSExclude10_4ElementsIconCreationOption];
```

Comment: No. Don't go creating hard links in user land. That's absolutely asking for users to break thinks and creates privileges problems.

Comment: @uchuugaka: Could you elaborate please?

Comment: If you create a hard link it is the same file. That means if some user deleted it from the desktop the delete the original.

Comment: @uchuugaka we have tested it if user delete the hard link then only hard link will get deleted there is no impact on original.

Comment: I had this EXACT same problem and struggled with it for months! This is a great solution I havent tested it yet but will try. Here is me struggling with this issue - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/174761/make-alias-take-icon-of-the-app-it-points-to?noredirect=1#comment205991_174761 - your note on the test where deleting that file doesnt affect the original file is very important, thank you, i will test this and report to you my experience!